# NS2, Node IP Addressing

Tags: ip, nodes, ns2

I want to assign IP address to each node in NS2. How can I do it? 
I want something like

```
node_(1) IP= 192.168.10.2
```

I have tried some other ways but does not seem to be working.

Answer (score 0):

In implementing IP in NS2 it's quite tricky, we should make a new perspective about IP in NS2 and the other simulator.
As far as I Know, IP Address in NS2 refers no Node ID number.

You can read this conversation below :
1) https://www.researchgate.net/post/In_NS2_when_we_start_a_simple_wireless_simulation_1_Where_is_the_IP_address_of_a_node_stored_2_How_is_the_address_assigned_when_it_is_created2

2)
 http://ns2ultimate.tumblr.com/post/1196152906/address-and-ip-routing-in-ns2